# generating xml string and passing in namespace

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

i am having trouble generating an xml string when i add a space name. This is how i want to generate my xml like

xml sample:

```
<Feedback xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Record>
        <ID>2FAC636E-F96C-4465-9272-760BAF73C0DF</QRCodeID>
        <SubID>10B5236C-47FD-468D-B88D-D789CA0C663A</SubmissionID>
        <UserID>1</UserID>
        <Page>1</Page>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>219C462B-B874-4408-AFBA-CA727922D50F</QRCodeID>
        <SubID>10B5236C-47FD-468D-B88D-D789CA0C663A</SubmissionID>
        <UserID>1</UserID>
        <Page>2</Page>
    </Record>
</Feedback>
```

What my code looks like now:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Feedback xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'",
                new XElement("Record",
                    new XElement("ID", idGuid),
                    new XElement("SubID", subGuid),
                    new XElement("UserID", 2),
                    new XElement("Page", pages)
                    )
            )
        );
```

when i run it throws an error here `"Feedback xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"` that it doesn't like the character ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) suggests that something like the following should work:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Feedback",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "j", "http://schemas.sitename.com/2013/03/Project.Models"),
        new XElement("Record",
            new XElement("ID", idGuid),
            new XElement("SubID", subGuid),
            new XElement("UserID", 2),
            new XElement("Page", pages)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: great thanks! also - if i wanted to add another namespace would i just add `+ "http://schemas.sitename.com/2013/03/Project.Models"` after the first link

Comment: I would just add another `XAttribute`.  See my edit.  Also, the page that I linked discusses this topic in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx), it explains everything you need to know

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to use [Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387042.aspx).

This is trying to create a markup with your entire string, which is invalid.